# Laravel 7: Dependent Select dropdown not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-7

I have two tables named departments and designations. I want to show the designations depending on the department selected. But my code is not working, I looked for the solution for 3 days but failed.

Department Table:

| id | department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IT |
| 2 | Accounts |

Designation Table:

| id | designation | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager | 1 |
| 2 | Manager | 2 |

Department Model:

```
 public function designation(){
   return $this->hasMany(Designation::class);
 }
```

Designation Model:

```
public function department(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/getdesignation','EmployeeController@getdesignation');
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function getdesignation(Request $request){
        $data=Designation::select('designation','id')->where('department_id',$request->id)->get();
        return response()->json($data);

    }
```

Blade:

```
<select name="department_id" id="department_id" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="" selected>Select one</option>
   @foreach($departments as $row)
    <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->department }}</option>
   @endforeach
 </select>
<select name="designation_id" id="designation_id" class="form-control" required></select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '#department_id', function() {
           var dpt_id = $(this).val();
           if (dpt_id) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'get',
                   url: '{!! URL::to('getdesignation') !!}',
                   data: {
                       'id': dpt_id
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                       if (data) {
                           $('#designation_id').empty();
                           $('#designation_id').append(
                               '<option hidden>Select Designation</option>');
                           $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                               $('select[name="designation_id"]').append(
                                   '<option value="' + key + '">' + value
                                   .designation + '</option>');
                           });
                       } else {
                           $('#designation_id').empty();
                       }

                   }
               });
           } else {
               $('#designation_id').empty();
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Also when I update the data, how to select the old value?

Comment: What does "*is not working*" mean, exactly?  Does your Javascript change handler work, and does the AJAX fire?  If yes, is the right `departmentID` used?  Does the server response work, eg if you view it in devtools (or visit that URL in your browser)?

Comment: when I hit the url it returns the value. But in browser network debugging mode, there shows 404 error

Comment: In my question, I have shared all the related code. Is there anything missing or should I check other files or code?

Comment: What is missing is your debugging :-) Open your [browser devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), and inspect what is happening.  Do you see any Javascript errors?  Click on the network tab, do you see your AJAX request happening?  If yes, is the right `departmentID` used?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see. Now the dropdown is showing. But in designation dropdown, value is not showing properly. It should show the designation table id value. Instead of this, it starts with 0. How can I get the designation table id value in key parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

```
var dpt_id = $(this).val();
```

Will return null as the element is a select input thus you will send department_id as null

Finally send null to request and get also null at response since null is not matched with any rows :)

So the first step is for you to get the value of the selected option by

```
var dpt_id = $(this).find(':selected').val()
```

It will return the value of the option which is selected

Secondly, Isn't it better to assign the designation id as option value instead the array index?

I assume you should use `value.id` instead using `key`

I think it helps you. And let me know the updates!

Comment: Thanks, in the edit page how can I auto-select the designation?